# Caching with cookies without caching Cookies

Tags: caching, cookies, varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

As per european rules on cookies, we need to display a message to let users know we use cookies.

When they accept, we set a cookie! Along with a heavy reliance on tracking cookies, we need this cookie :(

I have setup Varnish to cache both assets and my landing page, which has a huge impact on speeds, naturally. Assets are working a dream, the homepage is never receiving Set-Cookie from the server, as this is how Varnish is configured out of the box.

Our varnish server is Centos 7, it has installed Varnish 4. Our goal is to eventually move to Fastly, they have a guide to do exactly what I want to do, which is allow us to use Cookies and avoid caching them.

https://www.fastly.com/blog/how-to-cache-with-tracking-cookies

However, the req variables are no longer in scope in `vcl_deliver` in Varnish 4.

Has anyone been able to find a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just store the "Tmp-Cookie" in *beresp* rather than *bereq*, in which case it'll propagate up to *resp* in *vcl_deliver*. You can then copy it over to *Set-Cookie*.

So a modified version of the Fastly recommendation:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (beresp.http.Set-Cookie) {
        # ... so store it temporarily
        set bereq.http.Tmp-Set-Cookie = beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
        # ... and then unset it
        unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
    }
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.Tmp-Set-Cookie) {
        set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.Tmp-Set-Cookie;
        unset resp.http.Tmp-Set-Cookie;
    }
}
```

That should act equivalently to the response handling, but you will still want to handle the incoming request cookie most likely (if relevant).